# A good introduction to Cryptography

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

Excuse me in advance for the generality of the question I am about to ask, I am not even sure if this is the place to ask... but here I go!

Let me start by mentioning a little about my academic background:

I recently finished my Mathematics BSc and I am starting an MSc in Mathematics on September. I did my Final degree thesis on Tannakian Categories and I have a good background in topics such as algebraic number theory, algebraic geometry (I have a good knowledge of scheme theory) and algebraic topology. When it comes to programming, I know C, C++, Python and R.

And here's the question:

I would like to find a good book/online course in order to learn a bit about Cryptography, most preferably following a deep mathematical approach, but combining it with programming in any of the latter languages, so that I can see an application. I don't mind learning another language, by the way :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. i think **“ Introduction to Modern Cryptography “** by Jonathan Katz and
   Yehuda Lindell is a very good book for your requirements.
2. you could also try **"Foundations of Cryptography”** by Oded Goldreich.

Comment: *Foundations of Cryptography* is very theoretical.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer but he will relate to it because of its mathematic approach.

Comment: @odu9 Thank you very much! Both books are exactly what I was looking for.